# MySQL Display results using foreign key on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm

I have a table of USER and PORTFOLIO where I wish to display the user's name and the portfolio title, however the name is only retrievable using USER ID and I'm not sure how to get the information across on PHP to reach the other DB table.

```
USER
id | user_fname    | user_lname
01 | John          | Smith
02 | Katherine     | Blair

PORTFOLIO
id | portfolio_title   | portfolio_user_id
19 | ClassRoom         | 02
20 | RemoteIsland      | 02
21 | MilkTown          | 01
```

Right now in my PHP file,

```
if( $request->has('s_c'))
{
    $categoryid = $request->s_c;
    $results = DB::table('portfolio')
    ->leftJoin('portfolio_images', 'portfolio.id', 'portfolio_images.p_portfolio_id')
    ->where('portfolio_user_id', 'like', "%".$search_text."%")
    ->orwhere('portfolio_title', 'like', "%".$search_text."%")
    ->groupBy('portfolio.id')
    ->orderBy('portfolio.portfolio_added_date', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(12);

    if($categoryid != '')
        $results = $results->where('portfolio_category', $categoryid);
}
else
{
    $results = DB::table('portfolio')
    ->leftJoin('portfolio_images', 'portfolio.id', 'portfolio_images.p_portfolio_id')
    ->where('portfolio_user_id', 'like', "%".$search_text."%")
    ->orwhere('portfolio_title', 'like', "%".$search_text."%")
    ->groupBy('portfolio.id')
    ->orderBy('portfolio.portfolio_added_date', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(12);
}

return view('./frontend/portfoliotest', [
    'categories' => $categories,
    'results' => $results
]);
```

Which will display it such as

```
02  ClassRoom
02  RemoteIsland
01  MilkTown
```

But I want it to reach into the user table as well to get

```
Katherine Blair  ClassRoom
Katherine Blair  RemoteIsland
John Smith       MilkTown
```

I'm using $result to display the information from PORTFOLIO table, but how can I get the display of fname and lname of the user instead of it's ID

Comment: what database library is that?

Comment: do you want to keep the left join with table "portfolio_images" (although not showing them)?

Comment: Join users table then and select required fields.

Answer (score 0):

You should join users table and select the attributes that you need.
You can add this piece of code to the queries:

`->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'portfolio.portfolio_user_id')
->select('users.*', 'portfolio.portfolio_title')`

As the select method suggests, the results are user_fname, user_lname, portfolio_title